# How to add multiple body variables in blat

Tags: batch-file, blat

I have a script from which I am calling the body through a variable.

This working fine, but now I have two different variables. How can I call it in a body?

Eg:

```
set body1=%MAIN_DIR%\Monitor\one.html
set body2=%MAIN_DIR%\Monitor\two.html
%BLAT% %body1%%body2% -priority 1 -subject "%SUBJECT%" -f %FROM% -to %TO% -server %SMTP%
```

Note: `Body1` should be on one line, `Body2` should on the next line.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I don't believe blat supports multiple body files, so you'll need to get the contents into one file.

Comment: That is not possible as the content of both html is exactly the same. It displays a table in (Before) one.html and runs a procedure and then displays the two.html(after).

Comment: The thing is, I want to show before and after of the table content

Comment: You will have to send two separate emails then.